# Simulink product block output is attenuated, why?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using the Simulink's product block to mix a carrier with a wide-band signal. The output of the product block is as expected, but with an attenuation, why is that? The attenuation from my tests is about 5-10 dB.

Figures of system and spectrum content:

[Test bench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ9PN.png)
[image: img1]

[Carrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp8Xy.png)
[image: img2]

[Wideband](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGaZI.png)
[image: img3]

[Product output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7xnN.png)
[image: img4]

Comment: You need to provide some input in order to reproduce your case.

Comment: See the post update, any idea why this happens?

Comment: What is your expected product output? Remember multiplying in time domain is equivalent to convolution in frequency domain. It is not straight forward to quickly estimate the output spectrum in this case.